# 2014 Educational Content on Bitcoin

Tags: education

it's been a long time. I'm updating my udemy course on Bitcoin and I'm curious what educational content has been released since September of 2013 on Bitcoin. Specifically have you guys encountered an aggregated list or has someone taken up the mantle of BEP since I left?

Answer (score 1):

Besides your course, there's [Khan Academy's](https://www.khanacademy.org/economics-finance-domain/core-finance/money-and-banking/bitcoin/v/bitcoin-what-is-it), Stanford's [cryptography course](http://online.stanford.edu/course/cryptography), and a rather superficial course on lynda, amongst more scattered material.